# How to convert raw query into Laravel Eloquent way

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this raw query.
How can i convert this one into Laravel eloquent.

```
SELECT * FROM `results` AS q
INNER JOIN `answers`AS a ON q.question_id = a.question_id 
AND q.team1 = a.team1 
AND q.team2 = a.team2 
AND q.score1 = a.score1

// Table relationships.
results hasMany answers.
results hasMany predictions.
Prediction is another model here.
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `results` and `answers`?

Comment: results hasMany answers,and answers belongs to results. @BalrajAllam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i understood your question,you can't get relationship with joins.

Please try this query.

```
 Result::join('results as q', function ($join) {
            $join->on('answers.question_id', '=', 'q.question_id')
                ->on('user_answers.team1', '=', 'q.team1')
                ->on('user_answers.team2', '=', 'q.team2')
                ->on('user_answers.score1', '=', 'q.score1')
                ->on('user_answers.score2', '=', 'q.score2');
        })->get();
```

Now you can run another query to get relational data.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `Result` is table `results`'s model:

```
Result::join('answers', function ($join) {
    $join->on('answers.question_id', '=', 'results.question_id')
         ->on('answers.team1', '=', 'results.team1')
         ->on('answers.team2', '=', 'results.team2')
         ->on('answers.score1', '=', 'results.score1');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,Can i also fetch relationship along with result.
Like with('relation') using above query ?

Comment: What's the relationship between them? Append it to your question.

Comment: I have updated the questions,secondly i am getting "1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'answers'" while i run the above command.

Comment: I have edited my answer,  may be it works. If not, add table alias `as` to the first parameter of join method.